# Left Outer Join - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is wrong with this query? I just can't get it to execute on a Oracle 11G Database.

```
SELECT PH.ORD_NBR, PH.TEL_NBR, SM.NAME 
FROM ORD_HDR PH  
LEFT_OUTER JOIN STORE SM ON SM.COUNTY='1' AND 
SM.STORE_ID=PH.STORE_ID  WHERE PH.ORD_NBR='777894801' AND ROWNUM<=1
```

I get this errror

**ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended**

Comment: don't you need to give the table of reference to the ROWNUM?

Comment: The reason I am using table alias is beacuse there is a column whose name is the same in both the tables. So i tried accesssing using alias but even that does not work. How can i dereference columns with same name in such type of queries?

Comment: @ambe5960 Even without rownum it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER` should be 2 words, not `LEFT_OUTER`.